# Why do I need to uninstall Anti-Virus for a Windows update

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, anti-virus

A computer running Windows 10 1809 was complaining that its Windows installation would be soon outdated, so I did the sensible thing and started an update. However, the update hit a road-block as it failed to uninstall the Anti-Virus software, which needs special admin privileges. For completeness, the Anti-Virus in question is from TrendMicro.

After manually uninstalling the Anti-Virus, the update proceeded. Why is the Anti-Virus such an obstacle to the Windows update?

If this persists, then keeping the computers up to date will become a nuissance.

Comment: Uninstall TrendMicro; run the Windows Update; re-install TrendMicro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't "anti-virus" in general it is TrendMicro. They tend to require what they call "critical patches" before windows updates, and they also ask Microsoft for "Offer Block" and "Setup Block" to delay the Windows Update offer and/or block install of Windows Feature Updates if the critical patch hasn't been applied.

See for example: https://success.trendmicro.com/solution/1112083-compatibility-between-windows-10-and-officescan-apex-one

Comment: Maybe I am not fully understanding the linked article, but is there a simple update path, i.e. hit update button A, then hit update button B? Uninstalling or disabling security software does not feel right. A couple of days ago, a colleague wanted me to disable the anti-virus for trouble-shooting his banking app on his computer, I flat out refused. Everybody recommends keeping security software up to date; so I am very sceptical if I am required to disable or even uninstall it.

Comment: @DohnJoe you *should* be skeptical of anything that asks to remove or disable AV software. The article I linked (there are other older ones from on their website) is just evidence (in their own words) that TrendMicro often needs to patch or adjust their software before it is compatible with Windows. Is there a simple path? Patch Trend Micro first. If it is still not compatible, then get other software or investigate a newer version of the software. A simple google search suggests that  TrendMicro preventing or blocking Windows Update rollouts has been happening for years.

Comment: It was the Windows 10 update that suggested to uninstall the anti-virus. This is clearly not the behaviour, which is described in the linked article as "Setup Block"; which is what I would have expected. Weird ...

Comment: @DohnJoe Microsoft want you to use the latest version because it is easier for them to maintain security and trend micro are blocking that. Microsoft are basically telling you to remove the block by removing the product, as they have presumably given Trend too many chances to fix their software which they have not taken. It's not as if Microsoft doesn't have a pre release track (they do) which Trend could work on to get compatibility *before* major releases... Trend are choosing to be part of the problem rather than the solution.